# melt array with multiple value variable

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, reshape, reshape2

I have a multidimensional array `a`, and I want to format it into `out`. I used `melt` followed by `dcast`, but I wonder if there is a better way of doing it, without or without using `library(reshape)`?

```
library(reshape2)
(a=array(1:3^4,c(3,3,3,3),dimnames=list("d1"=paste("d1",letters[1:3],sep="-"),
                                       "d2"=paste("d2",letters[1:3],sep="-"),
                                       "d3"=paste("d3",letters[1:3],sep="-"),
                                       "d4"=paste("d4",letters[1:3],sep="-"))))
(out=dcast(melt(a,id.vars=c("d1","d2","d3")),d1+d2+d3~d4))
```

I am asking this question because

1. My solution feels somewhat repetitive because I am using `melt` followed by `cast` and specifying `d1,d2,d3` two times. I wonder if there is a more straightforward way of doing things.
2. It would be a good if there is an at least as compact solution that doesn't require loading an extra package.

So to reiterate, I will be happy with any of the following:

1. A more straightforward solution that requires `reshape2`
2. A more straightforward solution that doesn't require `reshape2`
3. An at least as compact solution that doesn't require `reshape2`

Comment: @akrun, added motivation.

Comment: `ftable(a)` gives you the same info, but a different structure.

Comment: ... which means that you could use `table2df(a)`, where [`table2df`](https://github.com/mrdwab/mrdwabmisc/blob/master/R/table2df.R) comes from my GitHub-only ["mrdwabmisc" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/mrdwabmisc).

Comment: @akrun, that still "melts" and then reshapes. `ftable` actually has all the attributes required to create a `data.frame` without going into a long form first. See the code in `table2df` [starting from line 140](https://github.com/mrdwab/mrdwabmisc/blob/master/R/table2df.R#L140)

Comment: @Ananda, I have upvoted your contributions because `table2df` does give me the desired output. However, without any offence intended, the whole idea of needing to install a non-CRAN package is a bit too troublesome for me. (I trust your code, it's just that the 'cost' of installing a non-CRAN package (the downloading, copying and pasting files, imagine sharing the script with collaborators) outweighs the benefit of the solution)

Comment: @qoheleth, no offence taken. Some of these functions may end up in official packages, but until then, they stay on GitHub. By the way, to my knowledge, CRAN does not check the accuracy of your code.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you won't just be copying and pasting code, but rather, either sharing a collection of scripts that could be `source`d, or even creating a package of your functions.

Keeping that in mind, it's easy for you to recreate the function that I referred to in the comments.

Here's `ftable(a)`:

```
ftable(a)
#                d4 d4-a d4-b d4-c
# d1   d2   d3                    
# d1-a d2-a d3-a       1   28   55
#           d3-b      10   37   64
#           d3-c      19   46   73
#      d2-b d3-a       4   31   58
#           d3-b      13   40   67
#           d3-c      22   49   76
#      d2-c ......................
# ................................
```

And its `attributes`:

```
attributes(ftable(a))
# $dim
# [1] 27  3
# 
# $class
# [1] "ftable"
# 
# $row.vars
# $row.vars$d1
# [1] "d1-a" "d1-b" "d1-c"
# 
# $row.vars$d2
# [1] "d2-a" "d2-b" "d2-c"
# 
# $row.vars$d3
# [1] "d3-a" "d3-b" "d3-c"
# 
# 
# $col.vars
# $col.vars$d4
# [1] "d4-a" "d4-b" "d4-c"
```

You can use these attributes to create a function that looks like this:

```
ftable2df <- function (mydata) {
  if (class(mydata) != "ftable") mydata <- ftable(mydata)
  dfrows <- rev(expand.grid(rev(attr(mydata, "row.vars"))))
  dfcols <- as.data.frame.matrix(mydata)
  names(dfcols) <- do.call(
    paste, c(rev(expand.grid(rev(attr(mydata, "col.vars")))), 
             sep = "_"))
  cbind(dfrows, dfcols)
}

ftable2df(a)
#      d1   d2   d3 d4-a d4-b d4-c
# 1  d1-a d2-a d3-a    1   28   55
# 2  d1-a d2-a d3-b   10   37   64
# 3  d1-a d2-a d3-c   19   46   73
# 4  d1-a d2-b d3-a    4   31   58
# 5  d1-a d2-b d3-b   13   40   67
# 6  d1-a d2-b d3-c   22   49   76
# 7  d1-a d2-c d3-a    7   34   61
# 8  d1-a d2-c d3-b   16   43   70
# 9  d1-a d2-c d3-c   25   52   79
# 10 d1-b d2-a d3-a    2   29   56
# 11 d1-b d2-a d3-b   11   38   65
# 12 d1-b d2-a d3-c   ............
# ................................
```

---

#### Update (non-base solution)

If you're not married to "reshape2" and are open to using a package as long as it's on CRAN, and if you are open to a solution that might be a little slower than `melt`ing and `dcast`ing your data, you can also look at `adply` from "plyr".

```
library(plyr)
adply(a, 1:3)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that 1) is short 2) only uses base R

```
cbind(do.call(expand.grid, dimnames(a)[1:3]), apply(a, 4, identity))

#     d1   d2   d3 d4-a d4-b d4-c
#1  d1-a d2-a d3-a    1   28   55
#2  d1-b d2-a d3-a    2   29   56
#3  d1-c d2-a d3-a    3   30   57
# etc
```

My original solution used `reshape` and was a bit goofy... I think this is preferable by a long way.

Comment: Clever. (+1) Nice solstice hat too :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto - thanks. I reckon I look awesome. Surprised you didn't `reshape` this problem so I had to step up.

Comment: It's slightly better performing than the OP's for this small dataset, but it still has the problem of "melting" and then reshaping that they said they were trying to avoid. Needless to say, `ftable` is the fastest, and I imagine that `ftable2df` shouldn't be too far behind since it's mostly mucking with `attributes`.

Comment: Your other go is definitely faster. Maybe I'll have to adopt that in my code somewhere....